# MVC ViewModel > JS ViewModel - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a js error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &" when I try to pass my serverside viewmodel in a clientside viewmodel (for knockout.js)

ViewModel

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
        public Factuur Factuur { get; set; }
        public List<Factuurlijn> Factuurlijnen { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
        //Create Viewmodel
        InvoiceViewModel ivm = new InvoiceViewModel();

        //Initialize vm objects
        int aantaldagentotvervaldatum = Convert.ToInt32(General.getParameter("defaultaantaldagentotvervaldatum"));

        Factuur i = new Factuur { factuur_nummer = 1, factuur_nummervoorvoegsel = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), factuur_datum = DateTime.Now, factuur_type = Ftype, factuur_vervaldatum = DateTime.Now.AddDays(aantaldagentotvervaldatum), factuur_kortingspercentage = Convert.ToDecimal(General.getParameter("defaultkortingspercentage")) };

        List<Factuurlijn> FLijnen = new List<Factuurlijn>{new Factuurlijn(){ factuurlijn_aantal = 0, factuurlijn_item="", factuurlijn_prijs=0 }};

        // add objects to viewmodel
        ivm.Factuur = i;
        ivm.Factuurlijnen = FLijnen;

        return View(ivm);
```

View

```
    @{
        //prepare viewmodel to assign to pas into js
        string initialData = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);

    }

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialDataJS = @(initialData)
    alert('initialdata : ' + initialDataJS);
</script>
```

My alert ain't triggered and the errors I get;

**in FF :** attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
Bronbestand: chrome://firebug/content/net/requestObserver.js

**in Chrome :** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

I have a feeling it goes wrong on the serialisation of the viewmodel before I try to assign it to a js variable, but I don't understand why...

I already tried

```
string initialData = Json.Encode(Model);
```

but no success...  Then I saw this in my js errors

Error: invalid property id

```
var initialDataJS = {&quot;Factuur&quot;:{&quot;factuur_id&quot;:0,&quot;factuur_nummervoorvoegsel&quot;:&quot;2012&quot;,&quot;factuur_nummer&quot;:1,&quot;factuur_type&quot;:&quot;F&quot;,&quot;bedrijf_id&quot;:0,&quot;factuur_naam&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_notities&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_details&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_datum&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1335443889648)\/&quot;,&quot;factuur_vervaldatum&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1336307889648)\/&quot;,&quot;factuur_kortingspercentage&quot;:0,&quot;factuur_betaald&quot;:false,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_naam&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_adres&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_postcode&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_gemeente&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_land&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_tel&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_fax&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_gsm&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_email&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_website&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_bedrijf_btw&quot;:null,&quot;factuur_deleted&quot;:false,&quot;bedrijf&quot;:null,&quot;bedrijfReference&quot;:{&quot;Value&quot;:null,&quot;EntityKey&quot;:null,&quot;RelationshipName&quot;:&quot;ScotaModel.facturen_ibfk_1&quot;,&quot;SourceRoleName&quot;:&quot;facturen&quot;,&quot;TargetRoleName&quot;:&quot;Bedrijf&quot;,&quot;RelationshipSet&quot;:null,&quot;IsLoaded&quot;:false},&quot;factuurlijnen&quot;:[],&quot;EntityState&quot;:1,&quot;EntityKey&quot;:null},&quot;Factuurlijnen&quot;:[{&quot;factuurlijn_id&quot;:0,&quot;factuur_id&quot;:0,&quot;factuurlijn_item&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;factuurlijn_aantal&quot;:0,&quot;factuurlijn_prijs&quot;:0,&quot;factuurlijn_btwbedrag&quot;:0,&quot;factuurlijn_btwpercentage&quot;:0,&quot;factuurlijn_datum&quot;:&quot;\/Date(-62135596800000)\/&quot;,&quot;factuurlijn_volgorde&quot;:null,&quot;factuurlijn_deleted&quot;:false,&quot;facturen&quot;:null,&quot;facturenReference&quot;:{&quot;Value&quot;:null,&quot;EntityKey&quot;:null,&quot;RelationshipName&quot;:&quot;ScotaModel.factuurlijnen_ibfk_1&quot;,&quot;SourceRoleName&quot;:&quot;factuurlijnen&quot;,&quot;TargetRoleName&quot;:&quot;facturen&quot;,&quot;RelationshipSet&quot;:null,&quot;IsLoaded&quot;:false},&quot;EntityState&quot;:1,&quot;EntityKey&quot;:null}]}
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I think I did a mistake on filling my model.  The invoicelines had to go directly under the invoice object instead of seperately.  but now I'm getting "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object X.Models.Factuur"

Comment: Hmm, not good. You cannot serialize objects automatically created with EF, because when a one to many relation is defined the one side object contains a collection of all many side objects, and simultaneously each of the many side object has a pointer to its related one side object. This create a circular reference father->collection->son object-> father. 

It is not possible to serialize object graphs containing circular references. In order for serializaton to work the object graph must be a tree. This, is in general a good practice for all objects passed to a View.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var initialDataJS = @(initialData)
```

to

```
var initialDataJS = @Html.Raw(initialData)
```

from Phil Haack http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Razor is trying to safely encode all those quotes, but you actually need them for the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace quote character. here is what i do

```
    var jsonStr = '@(Model.JSONData)';
    var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));

    viewModel = new JsModel(json);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

so in this example, you saved the data from server as a string in jsonStr variable and then replace double quotes with the help of regEx and parse it. which will create a json object.